# Template tag to update template context

Tags: django

I know how to write a template tag which updates template context. But the update is available only just after the tag it self.

Is there a way to write custom django template tag which would result in global template context update, like using TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS?

Answer (score 0):

The template is rendered step by step (sequentially), and obviously the context modified by a template tag would be available only after the template tag were called, not before.

Why not to use a context processor?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using [django sekizai tags](https://github.com/ojii/django-sekizai/)

By using it you can do something like this:

```
{% load sekizai_tags %}
<head>
  <script>
    {% renderblock 'googls_dfp' %}
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  {% block content %}
    {% addtoblock 'google_dfp' %}
      alert('Script is initialized before the body loads of this html document.');
    {% endaddtoblock %}
  {% endblock %}
</body>
```